# App has stopped working with no error specified

Tags: java, android

i have been looking for the error so much but i can't find whats wrong the keep the app to stop and crashes whenever i open it, i have looked for each error and tried to correct it but still i can't figure it out, i hope you can help me?

this is my

logcat

```
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Process: imamalsajadsayings.android.com, PID: 1559
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{imamalsajadsayings.android.com/imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     ... 11 mor
```

MainActivity.java

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.state2 );
mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("mytext","Second Activity");
         startActivity(i);
}
}
);
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items TO the action bar IF it IS present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mTextView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.second);
Intent i=getIntent();
String text=i.getStringExtra("mytext");
mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.two);
mTextView.setText(text);

}
}
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/two"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="hi"
android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:background="@drawable/images" >



                   <com.google.ads.AdView 
                   android:id="@+id/ad"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                   ads:adUnitId="a152b5665edfefd"
                   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                   ads:adSize="BANNER" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)                                                                         "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:clickable = "true"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (الخير كله في صيانة الإنسان نفسه)                                                                   "
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"             
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                    android:clickable="true" />

           </LinearLayout>

          </ScrollView>
```

Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="imamalsajadsayings.android.com"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="1.2">


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 


<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
             android:label="@string/app_name">

     <activity android:name="imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> 



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
   <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post the stacktrace. Declared activity in manifest?. Post manifest

Comment: post xml of `MainActivity`

Comment: 12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: seems fine. clean and build project

Answer (score 0):

It says right in your stacktrace :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Comment: i added import android.widget.LinearLayout; but still

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and building the whole project again?

Comment: @user3115742 i see nothing wrong with the code clean and build your project and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

as per your logcat this line may be the issue.

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.state2 );
```

Please check that the resource `R.id.state2` is a TextView and not linear layout!

Comment: `<TextView android:id="@+id/state2"` it is. op updated. check it

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project. Under eclipse: `Project -> Clean.` Under Android Studio: `Build -> rebuild project.`